# I need to make an asp: LinkButton perform a server side button OnClick while doing a client side action

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to make the server side function below work with the client side function below. Specifically, when I click the "btnSave" the "uploadFile_Click" is executed at the same time. I'm looking to put an AJAX function within the Javascript.

Server side function:

```html
 <asp:Button ID="uploadedFile" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
```

```html
protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
            {
                foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
                {
                    uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Attachments/"),
                    uploadedFile.FileName)); listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedFile.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Client side

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return saveCallReport();" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/>
```

```html
        function saveCallReport() {

            var selectedFranchises = "";
            var selectedGroups = "";
            var selectedContacts = "";
            var selectedTopics = "";

            var ID = $('#<%=txtID.ClientID %>').val();
            if (ID == '') ID = '0';

            var Created = $('#<%=txtCreated.ClientID %>').val();
            var Confidential = document.getElementById('<%=chkConfidential.ClientID %>').checked;
            var Description = $('#<%=txtDescription.ClientID %>').val();
            var Employee = $('#<%=ddlEmployee.ClientID %>').val();
            var Priority = $('#<%=ddlPriority.ClientID %>').val();
            var Type = $('#<%=ddlType.ClientID %>').val();

            var LstRight = document.getElementById("<%=lstSelectedFranchises.ClientID %>");
            for (i = 0; i < LstRight.length; i++) {
                selectedFranchises = selectedFranchises + LstRight.options[i].value + ',';
            }
            if (selectedFranchises == null)
                selectedFranchises = "";

            LstRight = document.getElementById("<%=lstSelectedGroups.ClientID %>");
            for (i = 0; i < LstRight.length; i++) {
                selectedGroups = selectedGroups + LstRight.options[i].value + ',';
            }
            if (selectedGroups == null)
                selectedGroups = "";

            LstRight = document.getElementById("<%=lstSelectedContacts.ClientID %>");
            for (i = 0; i < LstRight.length; i++) {
                selectedContacts = selectedContacts + LstRight.options[i].value + ',';
            }
            if (selectedContacts == null)
                selectedContacts = "";

            LstRight = document.getElementById("<%=lstSelectedTopics.ClientID %>");
            for (i = 0; i < LstRight.length; i++) {
                selectedTopics = selectedTopics + LstRight.options[i].value + ',';
            }
            if (selectedTopics == null)
                selectedTopics = "";

            var obj = {
                id: ID,
                created: Created,
                hqemployee: Employee,
                type: Type,
                priority: Priority,
                confidential: Confidential,
                description: Description,
                franchises: selectedFranchises,
                groups: selectedGroups,
                contacts: selectedContacts,
                topics: selectedTopics,
            };

            //alert(JSON.stringify(obj));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/CallReportDetail.aspx/saveCallReport") %>',
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                    //alert("Call Report has been saved to Call Report ID: " + result.d + " !");
                    $('#txtID').val(result.d);
                    window.location.replace("/CallReports/Details?Id=" + result.d);

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    
                    alert("There was a problem saving the Call Report: " + thrownError);

                }
            });

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: what does UploadImages refer to? `if (UploadImages.HasFiles)`

Comment: It's what was added in the designer.cs         /// <summary>
        /// UploadImages control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload UploadImages;